# What is the process for identifying a 20 year flood zone?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flood

I am currently working on an assignment where I need to model flood risk areas. Firstly I was asked to identify potential flood risk zones based on the following criteria:

1. identify areas that I would consider to have steep slopes. I think I have completed this task. I used the Slope tool here.
2. Identify a 20 year flood zone and base this on an estimated distance from rivers. Then repeat the task for a 100 year flood return. A guide value would be not to go beyond 2 kilometers for the 100 year and less for the 20 year. I have no idea how to even start this. I have googled different things have come up with extensions that can be used but we never went over any such extensions in the college practicals.

Comment: This should be a relatively simple analysis to do, at least if you don't want "accurate" results. Try: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30442/floodplain-generation-given-river-section-polylines-flood-level-elevation-point ; also http://wa.water.usgs.gov/pubs/ofr/floodgis/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would typically not base a flood zone on *distance from the river*, but instead on elevation (a very steep hill right next to a river is very low flood risk, for example). However, if you don't have elevation data, I guess distance can be a reasonable estimate.

Measuring distance from a river can be accomplished with the [Buffer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000). Create a buffer of the size you think valid for a 20 year flood distance, and for a 100 year flood distance. (What that distance might be, I'd hesitate to even guess!)

Comment: Thank you, I never even thought of the buffer tool. I really appreciate your help here :)

Comment: Hope it gives you the results you need! :)